# Struts2 - retrieve session object using another session object as key

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I'm new to struts2 and I'm trying to retrieve a session object using a dynamic session key.

My app flow is like this: User will hit the action from their browser

```
http://localhost:8080/prjcr/pad.action?userid=p02585@test.org
```

In the action class, I retrieve a list of values from a web service using p02585@test.org request param and store them in the session as follows:

```
//get the request parameter
userid=ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameter("userid);    
QDefn[] qDefn = proxy.getQDefns(userid); //webservice call   
List<QDefn> qdList = new ArrayList<QDefn>();   
qdList.add(Arrays.asList(qDefn));
```

Extract userid part of the request parameter to be used as the session key

```
userid = userid.substring("UserId", userid.substring(0, userid.indexof('@'));   
//The key itself is what we receive in the request parameter  
ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("UserId", userid);
```

and then push the associated list of values into session

```
ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(userid, qdList);
```

and forward to a JSP that displays this list in a select drop down as follows:

```
<s:select name="qdefn" 
id="qdefn" 

list="#session.%{#session.UserId}"  ---What is the notation here??

listKey="defnName"
listValue="defnName"
headerKey="ALLQD"
headerValue="All" > </s:select>
```

I've tried to pull the qdList from the session in jsp using a dynamic session key which is the userid. 
In java, we do it as session.get(userid). I am not able to get in terms with the OGNL notation yet. So, I dont know how to do it in Struts2/OGNL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you do a

```
System.out.println(ActionContext.getContext().getSession().getClass());
```

in your action you will get 'class org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap', but if you do a

```
out.println(session.getClass());
```

in your jsp you will get 'class org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade' or something like that (i use tomcat)

so try

```
session.getAttribute(userid);
```

instead of

```
session.get(userid);
```

Comment: Hi pbaris. Thanks for your reply. Do you mean to suggest using like the below for the list attribute in select tag in jsP?   list=session.getAttribute(userid). Will that work? Also, the session.getAttribuet(userid) will only get me the userid which I should use to get the corresponding list. Something like this: session.getAttribute(session.getAttribute(userid)). How can I do this in OGNL notation? I'm wondering, is this possible at all? Although, I dont know, doesnt mean its impossible.